# SelectionSort Algorithm using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am a rookie and I need help optimizing this `SelectionSort()` algorithm which I have tried using Python.

```py
def selectionSort(arr,an):
    for lastUnsortedInteger in range(an-1,0,-1):
        largest = arr.index(max(arr[0:lastUnsortedInteger+1]))
        swap(arr,largest,lastUnsortedInteger)
    return arr

def swap(arr,ai,aj):
    arr[ai],arr[aj] = arr[aj],arr[ai]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    an = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
    selectionSort(arr,an)
    print("Sorted using SelectionSort():\n")
    for ai in arr:
        print(arr)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you already incorporated a few of the suggestions from back when this was on StackOverflow, e.g. changing the inner loop to `max`. However, you do so in a very inefficient way:

- you create a slice of the list, O(n) time and space
- you get the `max` of that slice, O(n) time
- you get the `index` of that element, O(n) time

Instead, you can get the `max` of the `range` of indices, using a `key` function for comparing the actual values at those indices:

```
largest = max(range(0, lastUnsortedInteger+1), key=arr.__getitem__)
```

This way, this step has only O(n) time (for Python 3).

Some other points:

- the `an` parameter (the length of the array/list) is not necessary, you can use `len`
- in my opinion, it is a bit simpler looping from first to last index, and using `min` instead of `max` accordingly
- since the swap is a single line now and only used once, we could inline this directly into the sorting function
- the function modifies the list in-place, so no `return` is needed and might lead users to expect that the function does not modify the list but create a sorted copy instead
- technically, `arr` is not an array but a `list`, and you might prefer `snake_case` to `camelCase` (it's "Python" after all)

My version:

```
def selection_sort(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        k = min(range(i, len(lst)), key=lst.__getitem__)
        lst[i], lst[k] = lst[k], lst[i]
```

Needless to say, for all practical purposes you should just use `sorted` or `sort`.